# To infinitive vs gerund

Tags: word-usage

Consider these two sentences:

> 1. We will update the server to include more space.
> 2. We will update the server including more space.

Sentence 1 is the original sentence, but I was asked if sentence 2 could be used instead.

Sentence 2 feels incorrect, but I can’t explain why. If someone could explain to me why S2 is or is not correct I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, we could get away with the change if we used a different verb and added a comma:

> 1. We will update the server to add more space.
> 2. We will update the server, adding more space.

Both of those are grammatical. The first one explains the **purpose** for updating the server (to add more space). The second one explains a **consequence** of updating the server (adding more space).

The only problem with your S2 is that, in the phrase "including more space", the verb *include* doesn't fit well in that context. Grammatically, though, the verb *include* could work in different context. For example, a president of a university might say either one of these to the admissions office:

> 1. We will accept more applicants to include more international students.
> 2. We will accept more applicants, including international students.

The two sentences are not exactly equivalent, though. Once again, S1 states the driving **reason** for accepting more applicants (the university wants more international students enrolled). S2, on the other hand, **clarifies** the planned course of action: it's not just local student enrollments that will go up, but international students as well.

Comment: So there’s no rule or reason why the verb “include” in that aforementioned context does not work?

Comment: There is no "rule", but some verbs just don't work well in certain contexts. We paint walls, not vegetables. We don't typically _include_ more space, we _add_ more space. _Include_ is a tricky word, though, because it gets used in contexts like, "We need to by new parts, to include a new alternator." That just means an alternator is on the list of parts we need to buy. Maybe _include_ works better with tangible objects, so that's why it sounds strange with "space"? I'm not sure, though; it's not like we get taught rules like this in middle school. It's more subtle than that.

Comment: Lol yeah I hear ya. Thanks a lot for the response. It was helpful.